# How to also populate "N/A" with If AND function in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My current formula populates Missed, Meets, Nearly Meets, and Exceeds. But I can't seem to figure out how to include "N/A" or create a blank cell in the formula.

My forumla so far:

```
=if(AND(L40>=14.5, L40<=16.4),"Nearly Meets", if(AND(L40>=4.5, L40<=14.4),"Meets", if(AND(L40>=15.5),"Missed","Exceeds")))
```

So, if L40 has any range of these number, M40 populates any of these Texts. How can I add to the formula so a blank cell populates "N/A" . Or, entering "TBD" in a cell leaves it blank or populates "N/A"

Comment: OK, first: is your last range `L40 >= 15.5` correct? If so, you should fix the first one (`L40>=14.5, L40<=16.4`), because you'll end up always in one of those, rendering the other useless. Also, for a single comparison, you don't need the `AND()`. 
Can you better specify the ranges you need (meets, nearly meets, etc.) and when it exceeds or is N/A?

Comment: add one more check for an empty value `=if(L40<>"",if(AND(L40>=14.5, L40<=16.4),"Nearly Meets", if(AND(L40>=4.5, L40<=14.4),"Meets", if(AND(L40>=15.5),"Missed","Exceeds"))),)`

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather use IFS formula or VLOOKUP here. It's short and clear.

```
=ifna(vlookup(B2,F2:G6,2,true),"value not found")
```

[image]

On a side you make a table of requirements and go through it using vlookup.
If you have no space anywhere in your sheet, you can also include value table into your formula using curly brackets:

```
=ifna(vlookup(B2,{0,"Missed";4.5,"Nealry Meets";14.4,"Meets";15.5,"Exceeds";"","Empty"},2,true),"value not found")
```

For values outside the set you can use IFNA formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you use indentation before writing the final formula, it looks like this:

```
if(AND(L40>4.4; L40<=16.4){
    "Nearly Meets"; 
}

else if(AND(L40>=4.5; L40<=14.4){
 "Meets";
}

else if(L40>16.4){
    "Missed"; 
}

else if(L40 = ""){
    "N/A"; 
}

else {
    "EXCEEDS"
}
```

Notice that I didn't use the condition `if(L40<4.5)`, because a blank cell can be interpreted as `0`, which is always less than `4.5`, so you would never reach the `N/A` condition. By better determining your ranges, it gets easier to escape the `exceeds` case. It may not be your case, but if you had 2 or more digits after the decimal point, it could give you an unexpected result.

That said, you can now use the formula as

```
=if(AND(L40>4.4, L40<=16.4), "Nearly Meets", if(AND(L40>=4.5, L40<=14.4), "Meets", if(L40>16.4, "Missed", if(L40 = "", "N/A", "EXCEEDS"))))
```